# Prove that if there exists injections between two sets, then there exists a bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm learning the cardinality of an infinite set, and there is a statement below. I want to know how to prove it

if there exists an injective map from X to Y and an injective map from Y to X (these
two maps need not be inverse to each other), then there exists a bijection between X and Y .

Comment: It's an exercise on which you are supposed to spend some time thinking ... instead of just asking for an answer here.

Comment: Hint [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)